# How to create a merge request for forked repo into main repo via Gitlab REST Api

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api, merge-request

What I try to accomplish to merge changes of forked repo into main repo. Both repo’s master branch are protected. I can accomplish it via Gitlab web pages. But unfortunately, Gitlab rest api for merge request does not have [source_project_id](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#create-mr) attribute.

Is there any way to create merge request via command line for forked repo into main repo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the API, you would use the MR endpoint for the *source project* -- the fork that you created.

Suppose the "main" project is `owner/main-project` and your fork is `user/main-project-fork`

You would use the MR API endpoint (`/projects/:id/merge_requests`) using the `id` (or url-encoded path) of `user/main-project-fork`. Then you would provide the [`target_project_id` parameter](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#create-mr) using the ID of the `owner/main-project` project.

Comment: thanks, documentation is not clear about that. How could you find solution, by trying..

Comment: @GurselKoca I agree the docs could be made more clear. There is a small nuance in the documented URL `id` parameter: `The ID or URL-encoded path of the project owned by the authenticated user` -- that is to say, you certainly own your fork, but you may not necessarily own the upstream project. It can be ambiguous/confusing if you actually own both projects.